# Node express repopulate form values

Tags: node.js, express

Suppose a form has the following input element:

```
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

After user committing the form, and the validation failed, 
express should send back the value to repopulate the value of `username` text field

```
res.render('/user/sign', { username: username});
```

then the form should be

```
<input type="text" name="username" value = "<%= typeof username!='undefined' ? username : ''" %> />
```

I don't like the above code, too much codes are there. 
Is there any easy way to repopulate the form value?

Comment: Yes, use client-side `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` instead of relying on the server to do it for you.

Comment: any example link of sessionStorage or localStorage for this scenario?